# How to encode subgraphs as hyperedges

Tags: graph-theory, coding-theory, hypergraphs

Hi i was reading a paper "Propagating Distributions on a Hypergraph by Dual Information Regularization by Koji Tsuda", and one section stood out to me.

> hypergraphs have more flexibility
>   in describing prior knowledge, because known
>   clusters can be directly encoded as hyperedges. It
>   might be possible to convert a hypergraph to a conventional
>   graph, for example, by converting a hyperedge
>   to a complete subgraph.

My question is how exactly can one encode a small cluster into a hyperedge and how can one go in reverse. I've tried googling it but I've come up short.

Comment: I suggest to add information and coding theory tags.

Comment: Is there any particular information i could add to make it more clear?

Comment: I am not familiar with this kind of coding just I guessed that coding tag perhaps useful. If you do not receive an answer in this forum, maybe email to [Shahrooz Janbaz user](https://mathoverflow.net/users/19885/shahrooz-janbaz) be useful because, he is working on [Coding theory and Graph theory](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Shahrooz_Janbaz). The last thing that I can mentioned is that if you find an example in this subject and add to your question, it makes your question clear.

Comment: I have no idea how to contact him. Is there a way i can tag him or something? Again thanks for the help.

Comment: You can post your question in [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) or download one of the his papers like [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/285288838_Sparse_codes_derived_from_graphs) and find his email and contact him.